# How to load database values to the table in symfony2?

Tags: php, database, debugging, symfony, twig

I want to update table from values which are stored in the database.
I have included this code snippet in the controller file.

```
$emanager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository= $emanager->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:ExamTry');
$students= $repository->findAll();
return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Principal:Results.html.twig',
array('students'=>$students));
```

I have included below code in the html twig.

```
{% for student in students%}
    <tr>
        <th>Head1</th>
        <th>Head2</th>
        <th>Head3</th>
        <th>Head4</th>
        <th>Head5</th>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

When I render this code I could get no result.
I really grateful some one can answer to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean it does not show any row `<tr>`? Can you dump the count of your result in your twig file and see if there is any data returned? `{{ dump(students|length) }}`

Comment: when I dump It simply return 'array(0) { }' value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this in your Twig:

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Head1</th>
      <th>Head2</th>
      <th>Head2</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   {% for student in students %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{ student.field1 }}</td>
         <td>{{ student.field2 }}</td>
         <td>{{ student.field3 }}</td>
      </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```